# Understanding "Application has not been registered" error

Tags: react-native

I've been given a new React Native app to maintain and whenever I build it or run it in the simulator, I get the ["Application has not been registered" error](https://docs.expo.dev/troubleshooting/application-has-not-been-registered/). There are no other errors in the console before this message (although there are some warnings). I can't find any code issues as if the error message is dismissed in the simulator, the app runs fine so the bundler is running correctly, although on an actual device, this registers as a crash on open.

I'm running in the simulator using `react-native run-ios` from the project root. Builds for running on actual devices is managed by Fastlane.

My app doesn't make an explicit call `AppRegistry.registerComponent` due (I think) to the way `react-native-navigation` is set up, so most of the info online about this error doesn't apply.

Where should I go next to figure this out?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683866/application-has-not-been-registered-react-native-navigation-v2?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just npm start again can solve your problem as well.

`npm start`